# How to permanently +1 a variable outside of a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Python script that pulls cryptocurrency data from Yahoo Finance. It scrapes this data and then inputs it into a Google Sheet. What I want is for this script to run once per day, which I will schedule through task scheduler, and each day pull the data from Yahoo Finance and then input into the sheet.

I want this spreadsheet to store data historically. For example, first column = today's data, second column = tomorrow's data (which the script will collect when it runs tomorrow) which means the column value needs to +1 after the script runs every time. I've put the column number into a variable, so what I'm essentially trying to do is this;

today, c 
tomorrow, c + 1
day after, c + 2

and so on, so that the sheet gets filled out and the data doesn't get overwritten. I doubt there's a way to permanently change the value of the variable other than going into the script and changing the value of c manually before it runs. Is there any other way to go about this?

Not sure how to tackle this - c = c + 1 at the end of the function was my best guess but I know this won't work. The only other thing I can think of is to write out this function hundreds of times, first time c = 1, second time c = 2 and so on with "time.sleep(86400)" in between functions and have the script running constantly but as you can imagine I'd rather not do that.

```py
def google_sheet_import(var1):
    r = 2
    c = 3
    for w in (var1):
        cc_worksheet.update_cell(r, c, w.text)
        r = r + 1

    google_sheet_import(intraday_price)
```

All that happens is the script overwrites the data in c because I can't get it to permanently change the value of c after the script runs.

Comment: Read the latest value of `c` from the sheet when starting the program?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish your needs, you have many possible options to follow:

1. Store the `c` value somewhere in your sheet. After inserting a new column, you should increment it, and before inserting a new one you should read it and set it to be `c`'s value.
2. Store the `c` variable in a file (see python's [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function) and increment it accordingly.
3. The one that is probably the most sensible and the one I will provide code for. Compute the number of columns you have in your sheet when the python script is executed, and then assign `c`'s value based on that:

```py
def google_sheet_import(var1):
    r = 2
    c = len(cc_worksheet.get_all_values()[0])
    for w in (var1):
        cc_worksheet.update_cell(r, c, w.text)
        r = r + 1

    google_sheet_import(intraday_price)
```

The only change is in the 3d line. What it does is to check which is the last cell that is populated **within the first row** (in case your first row is empty or can be empty, I recommend that you set it to another row that you know will be populated).